# Flexslider - show tooltip while mouse hover on dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ flex slider plugin in my page.

```
Below is my code for flexslider:

html: 
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>Image 1</li>
        <li>Image 2</li>
        <li>Image 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

js: java script code for flex slider and this code is used to initialize the flex slider while page load.

    $(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({   
                animation: "slide",
                slideshow: false,
                controlNav: true,
                directionNav: false,
                easing: "swing"
            });
        });
```

All, I want is when I mousehover to dots (which used for navigation among slides) a tooltip should reneder and show some kind of message say "Slide number".

Comment: Just give title attribute for anchor element kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/u37p2jcs/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by RRR, I have added `title` to each of the dots.

```
$(".flexslider ol li a").each(function(index){
   $(this).attr("title","slide number "+(index+1));
});
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/5yx4x7jL/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help

Comment: Now i have to show image name on each dot on mouse hover event below is the html code:                                                                 <div class="flexslider">
 <ul class="slides">
  <li> <p> burger1 </p>
            <img src="burger.jpg"/>
        </li>
  <li> <p> burger2 </p>
            <img src="burger1.jpg"/>
        </li>
  <li> <p> burger3 </p>
              <img src="burger2.jpg"/>
        </li>
 </ul>
  </div>