# Flexslider when hover the indicators the image inside it will show up

Tags: html, css

[image]

i want to achieved this layout. when i hover the flexslider indicators the image inside it will show. id refer to this article [Flexslider - show tooltip while mouse hover on dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739734/flexslider-show-tooltip-while-mouse-hover-on-dots) but this was referring to the image title and not the image inside it.

Comment: there is no none property to visibility. you can use hidden instead of none

Comment: sorry for the wrong code i want to show the testimage when hover to the flexslider indicator i edited the code to this .flex-control-nav li a:hover + .testimage { visibility:visible; }

Comment: @PritoNito you will need to provide your html markup to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: my problem is that i can't show a specific div in a flexslider indicators

Comment: I refer to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739734/flexslider-show-tooltip-while-mouse-hover-on-dots..but this only shows the title of the image..i want to show image associated with specific indicators

Comment: @PritoNito here are enough people that could help, but you need to create a better topic. Refer to this guide and rewrite your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` has no `none` property. Use some of these instead:

```
visibility: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;
```

[W3 schools about visibility property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

To show your image you need to set `visibility: visible`. You can check this [**js fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ju5whrh3/1/).

Comment: yes i set the testimage to visibility: hidden and so that when i hover the flexslider indicator the testimage will now set to visibility: visible

Comment: thank you your code is working on a simple div, but when I try your code in flexslider indicators still not working. :(

Comment: Has anybody here know the work around for this... :(